# How to add DbContext based on environment in ASP.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This is how I am currently adding my DbContext in my ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    .....

    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySQL(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    .....

}
```

And my connection string is stored in my appsettings.json file, like this for example:

```
{
    ....
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost;user id=root;password=root;database=mydb;sslmode=none"
  }

  ....

}
```

If I want to switch which database is being connected, how do I make the "services.AddDbContext()" switch the database if it is "Development" vs. "Production" environments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can configure different environment connection strings in different `appsettings` files like this-

For test environment, use appsettings.**test**.json

```
 "Data": {
    "MyDbContext": {
      "ConnectionString": "" /*<<== TestDatabase connection string */
    },
```

For prod environment, use appsettings.**prod**.json

```
 "Data": {
    "MyContext": {
      "ConnectionString": "" /*<<== ProdDatabase connection string */
    },
```

Use `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable to set current environment as Test or Prod values.

In Startup, you can use like this-

```
     services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:MyContext:ConnectionString"]));
```

Comment: Don't forget you can also include the environment specific JSON file: `.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)`

Comment: @DavidG I think, this is available by default in asp.net-core VS2015 template.

Comment: @DavidG, this is included by default, but I was wondering what that was for. Thanks!

Comment: @Sanket Indeed but I wouldn't rely on people using Visual Studio (or even developing on .Net Core on Windows.)

Comment: @big_water This is to load these additional appsettings files.

Comment: @DavidG, when you use appSettings.prod.json, does it only replace the related sections in appSettings.json?  Or does it replace the whole file?

Comment: @big_water Environment specific JSON files will override the settings you put in them, you don't need to include the entire file. You can also add as many additional files as you want.

Comment: @Sanket, what if the database types are different, for example for test using sqlite and for production using sqlserver ?