# How do I dynamically choose a connection string based on Environment in .Net Core startup?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In the StartUp class's Configure method of ASP.Net MVC Core, "IHostingEnvironment env" is passed in via Dependency Injection.
And decisions can be made based on the environment. For example,

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
```

In ConfigureServices, I want to do something like this to pick the correct Connection string.
Something like:

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        }
        else if (env.IsStaging())
        {
            // Add Staging Connection
        }
        else
        {
            // Add Prod Connection
        }
```

But "IHostingEnvironment env" is not passed in to the ConfigureServices method by default.
So I modify the signature from:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
```

to

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IHostingEnvironment env)
```

and in ConfigureServices put:

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        }
        else if (env.IsStaging())
        {
            // Add Staging Connection
        }
        else
        {
            // Add Prod Connection
        }
```

So now when I run I get this error message:

"The ConfigureServices method must either be parameterless or take only one parameter of type IServiceCollection."

ConfigureServices() won't take in the IHostingEnvironment var.

But "Startup.StartUp(IHostingEnvironment env)" does.
I thought about adding a StartUp class field and setting it to the correct environment from Startup() and then using that field to make the decision flow in ConfigureServices.  But this seems like a hack.

I know environment is a first class concept in .Net Core.
Is there a way to do this straight from appsetting.json?

What is the best practice to accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add DbContext based on environment in ASP.net Core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267506/how-to-add-dbcontext-based-on-environment-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 6):

**Update**
Like Sam said, Joe's solution, though works fine, this is a hack. As of ASP.Net Core 1.1, the correct approach of using different connection for different environment is to handle it from the appsettings.json file itself rather then checking for the environment in the ConfigureServices method. The project by default comes with **appsettings.json** and **appsettings.Development.json** files (a different one for Staging can be created manually using the naming convention, if need be)

So in Joe's solution you will not need to set the value of the environment in the constructor nor need to use it to check hosting environment it in the ConfigurServices. So get rid of:

> environment = env;
>  
>   ........
>
> public IHostingEnvironment environment { get; set; }
>   ........
>   //Also, get rid of if /else in the ConfigureServices method.

So your ConfigureServices method will just inject:

> 

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Now, your **appsettings.json** will have:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "//Value of your connection string for Production Env."
  }
```

and your **appsettings.Development.json** will have:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "//Value of your connection string for Development Env."
      }
```

Now, if you look at the constructor method, var **builder** already loads both appsettings files and depending upon if you are running the project in development environment or published production environment, it will use the correct file and hence the settings defined in them.

Comment: Is worth mentioning that one should never store production sensitive data in configs like that. I know it's just an example but.. never know how people misuse stuff :) For prod config the way to go is always using environment variables.

Answer (score 2):

IHostingEnvrionment is passed into the constructor of Startup, from there you can persist it to a property and then use it from ConfigureSerivces

```
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        // add this file name to your .gitignore file
        // so you can create it and use on your local dev machine
        // remember last config source added wins if it has the same settings
        builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.dev.json", optional: true);
        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();

        environment = env;
    }

    public IHostingEnvironment environment { get; set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    if (envirnoment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }
    else if (envirnoment.IsStaging())
    {
        // Add Staging Connection
    }
    else
    {
        // Add Prod Connection
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like the best practice to me or Microsoft ASP.Net Core team would have just let you inject IHostingEnvironment into ConfigureServices() like they do in Configure() and Startup().  This is the hack I mentioned I had already thought of in the original post but was looking for a better way.  I guess I will probably go with this until I find the correct solution.  Thanks for the feedback though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this by taking leverage of the [Environment based Startup class and methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments#environment-based-startup-class-and-methods). So, you could do something like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProductionConnection")));
}

public void ConfigureStagingServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("StagingConnection")));
}

public void ConfigureDevelopmentServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

As far as common services between environments, you can extract them into a private method and just call it on Configure{Environment}Services. Also, consider not having the production connection string in source control. You can set it and read it as an [Environment Variable on the machine.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?tabs=visual-studio#environment-variables)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add that setting as an enviroment variable on the enviroment, so the application fetches it from the environment variable with a different value for each enviroment.

Another way is to use Azure App Configuration with labels for production etc.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-labels-aspnet-core?tabs=core5x

```
configBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options => {
    options.Connect(configuration["connection_string"])
           .Select(KeyFilter.Any, LabelFilter.Null)
           .Select(KeyFilter.Any, "Development");
});
```