# How do I set the OnConfiguring method in my DbContext without any hardcoded connection string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using multiple examples on how to set up my MySql service but in almost every one (including the Microsoft), they are using a hard coded connection string.

This is my startup:

```
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.UseMySql(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
        mysqlOptions =>
        {
            mysqlOptions.ServerVersion(new ServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 18)));
        });
    });
```

And whenever I try to `Update-Database` I see an error telling me that there's no password setted

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

After looking around a bit I found an overrideable method called `OnConfiguring`, but I want to set the connection string in a dynamic way, cause If I change my environment, I want that string to change too.

This is where I found almost every example with hardcoded strings (ex. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html)

Comment: can you show how your connectionString looks in the config file?

Comment: Why did you call your connection string hardcoded when it's retreived from configuration?

Comment: The error is that  user does not have permision to connect to the server 'localhost'.To use different connections for different envs,you could configure connection strings in different `appsettings.{env}.json` file.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267506/how-to-add-dbcontext-based-on-environment-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 3):

I am addressing this portion of your question:

"After looking around a bit I found an overrideable method called OnConfiguring, but I want to set the connection string in a dynamic way, cause If I change my environment, I want that string to change too."

In order to solve getting the connection string into the OnConfiguring method inside your DbContext class I simply passed IConfiguration into the DbContext constructor like this.

```
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public CoreDbContext(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public CoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<CoreDbContext> options, 
                         IConfiguration config) : base(options)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
```

Then in the OnConfiguring method I pulled the connection string from that config object injected at construction. Like this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("YourKeyValueForConnStringInAppSettings.json"));
        }
    }
```

Finally here are details of my environment / Project:

- Windows 10 machine
- Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.0.4)
- ASP.NET Core Web API
- .NET 6.0
- Configure for HTTPS
- Use controllers checked
- Enable OpenApi support
- Authentication type at time of writing is None

Answer (score 1):

You need to init configuration if not configured.

This can be done by overriding the `OnConfiguring` method in `DbContext`.

This way you can have global application configuration that will be pulled when application is ran. And use local configuration when doing Db migration.

Try this

```
public class YourContext: DbContext
{

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        if (options.IsConfigured == false)
            options.UseMysql({YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING});
    }
}
```

Comment: Very uncomfortable with hard coding connection string in OnConfiguring. Seems there must be a way to get the string from appsettings.json, secrets, or whatever. Anybody know how?

Comment: This is bad practise and exactly what the OP was trying to avoid doing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535471/how-do-i-set-the-onconfiguring-method-in-my-dbcontext-without-any-hardcoded-conn#comment105240943_59535558), I think you want to separate the EF Core related classes to a different assembly.

In the `UseMySql` there is an option to configure `MigrationsAssembly`. You can get more details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/T_MySql_Data_EntityFrameworkCore_Infraestructure_MySQLDbContextOptionsBuilder.htm)

Here is pseudo-code for SQL Server.

```
services.AddDbContext<EFCoreDemoContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
            assembly => assembly.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(EFCoreDemoContext).Assembly.FullName));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in configuration file, you should have a ConnectionStrings that points to your database with other options.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "DefaultConnection": "server=127.0.0.1;uid=root;pwd=12345;database=test"
},
```

When you use configuration.GetConnectionString, you are looking up a value from the configuration section.

Comment: But how do I inject the IConfig when I'm working in another project?

Answer (score 0):

Try this at startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public Startup(IConfiguration config) 
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the 
    container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MainContext>(options => 
           options.UseOracle(_config["CONNECTION_STRING"]));
    }
 }
```

And do that at your Context ctor

```
public MainContext(DbContextOptions<MainContext> options) : base(options) { }
```